# Magento 2: Filter order collection on "created_at" attribute

Tags: magento2, orders, filter, datetime

I want to filter order collection using 'created_at' attribute but the problem is, values stored in 'created_at' attribute is in this format `2014-03-18 06:57:11` (Combination of date and time) and I want to apply filter with only this format `2014-03-18`(Date without time).

Please suggest me some solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can filter collection by this code

```
$from = date("Y-m-d 00:00:00"); // current date
$ordersList=Load order collection
$ordersList->addFieldToFilter('created_at', array('from' => $from));
```

Or you can pass value like below

```
$to = date("Y-m-d h:i:s"); // current date
$from = strtotime('-24 hours', strtotime($to));
$from = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', $from); // 24 hours before
$ordersList=Load order collection
$ordersList->addFieldToFilter('created_at', array('from' => $from));
```